# Cannot enter Debugging Mode in R

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I tried to debug a loop, and while I was able to set a breakpoint, when I ran the code block it did not get into the debugging mode.

[image]

Everything is also grayed out under the Debug menu. Was my set up not correct?

[image]

(My console)

[image]

I tried to follow this article but was lost halfway through https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200713843.

Thank you!

Comment: You can add `browser()` at line 60.

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output! [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you set a breakpoint in a script, not in a function.  There are limits to doing that, because R only records locations from a source file when the `source()` function is used.  In RStudio, this means you need to click on `Source`, not `Run` in the source pane.